# Using Eclipse "export as Runnable Jar" without configurations

Tags: java, eclipse

There should be something wrong in the way I'm using Eclipse, so let me explain:
I have a folder in the project marked as src, in order to have my configuration being deployed correctly in the classpath when Eclipse compile my project. This works fine since in debugging/running from the IDE works just fine. But if I export the project as a runnable jar file, the config files are embedded in it, and as a result I can't allow the user change the configuration ( I have to remove manually the file from the jar, and put in the current dir in order to achieve the desired behavior). Is there some solution to have this automatic? I did something like this: exported the "Export as a runnable JAR" as an ANT file, then manually modified it to work as I want, but unfortunatelly I have to manually update the file when class path changes. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse when you choose export option, you'll see JAR file, Javadoc and Runnable JAR file. Can you try JAR file option, where you can select/deselect the classpath along with the project? It also has an option to select only the class files without resources. Hope that option will be useful.

Comment: can the jar file creat ea runnable jar too?

Comment: No. That's the limitation in that :( The jar created will be a standard jar file, you have to specify the class with the main method on the command line when running the jar